# How to redirect to a page after selecting two links

Tags: jquery

What I am trying to do is that I have multiple links like

```
<a href="#" id="1"></a>
<a href="#" id="2"></a>
<a href="#" id="3"></a>
<a href="#" id="4"></a>
<a href="#" id="5"></a>
```

When I select two of the links it should redirect to the other page like.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   $('a').click(function()
   {
      var id1 = $(this).attr('id');
      $(this).css({"background-color": "blue"});
    });

});
```

Now I am confused how do I get second `id` and then redirect like this

```
   window.location.href="abc.php?id1="+id1+"&id2="+id2;
```

Comment: You need an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of your IDs in an array and when you hit the desired amount of IDs you want to click, get them out of there and append them to your `window.location.href` like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Define the array
  var ids = [];
  $('a').click(function() {
    // Push IDs to it
    ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
    $(this).css({
      "background-color": "blue"
    });
    // When it has the right amount of ids append it
    if (ids.length === 2) {
      window.location.href = "abc.php?id1=" + ids[0] + "&id2=" + ids[1];
    }
  });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/putvande/s1fwLa1v/)

This way if you want to have more or less IDs you can easily scale it.

Or better yet

```
if (ids.length === 2) {
  // Create the "id1=1&id2=2"
  var params = ids.map(function(id, index) {
    return "id" + (index + 1) + "=" + id;
  });

  window.location.href = "abc.php?" + params.join('&');
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/putvande/s1fwLa1v/1/)

Comment: The array part made me aware a lot. I can now manipulate arrays in jquery! Thanks a lotttt!

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure why you want to do this, but that is the most obvious solution:

If there's no first identifier, store it. If there is, redirect.

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
   var id1;
   $('a').click(function()
   {
      if (!id1) {
        id1 = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).css({"background-color": "blue"});
        return false;
      }
      window.location.href="abc.php?id1="+id1+"&id2="+$(this).attr('id');
      return false;
    });

 });
```